# How to access value from dict (nested models object) in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
views.py


<pre>class BoardDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Board
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['columns'] = Column.objects.filter(board = self.get_object())
        context['labels'] = Label.objects.filter(board = self.get_object())

        for column in context['columns']:
            context[str(column)] = Task.objects.filter(column = column)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
        context['tasks'] = tasks
        print(context)
        return context </pre>
```

from the 1st print stmt I got four obj  [progress, bugs, finished, delayed] i.e. <QuerySet [<Column: progress>, <Column: bugs>, <Column: finished>, <Column: delayed>]>

and from 2nd print stmt I got these obj which are dependent on first four.

{'progress': <QuerySet [<Task: 1 - elementorTemplate>, <Task: 2 - logodesign>]>, 'bugs': <QuerySet [<Task: 6 - fix model>]>, 'finished': <QuerySet []>, 'delayed': <QuerySet [<Task: 3 - watermark>]>}

I am unable to access value in template. please help me.

Template.py

{% for column in columns %}

```
   <div class="grid-item">
        <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'board-detail' column.id %}">{{ column.title }}</a>
             {% for task in column.title%}     <! –– ––>
              <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ tasks.color_category }}</a>
                <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ task.title }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ task.description }}</small>
                <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ task.priority }}</a>
                <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ board.task.labels }}</a>
              </div>

              {% endfor %}
              {% endwith %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the related tasks of columns into the context. The way you are doing things you end up with an unnecessary amount of keys in your context. You can simply loop over related objects in the template by using the `related_name`. If you don't set a related name it is automatically the model name in lower case with `"_set"` appended.
I assume `Task` has a foreign key to `Column` hence you can change your code as follows:
Your views:

```
class BoardDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Board
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['columns'] = Column.objects.filter(board = self.get_object())
        context['labels'] = Label.objects.filter(board = self.get_object())
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.all()
        context['tasks'] = tasks # Where does this variable come from?? If it is global I recommend not to use it.
        print(context)
        return context
```

Now in your template where you want the tasks of a column:

```
{% for task in column.task_set.all %} <!-- Assuming related name not set and using default task_set -->
<!-- Your code here -->
{% endfor %}
```

I think `Column` and `Label` also seem to have a foreign key to `Board` hence you can do something similar for them instead of passing them to the context.

Comment: It worked for me.'task' is not variable I just used to for debug and forgot to remove. As you suggested I used 'select_related' for Column and Label it works fine for me an save some query fetching time.